# Extension of trace preserving $*$-homomorphisms on dense subalgebras of von Neumann algebras.

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras, von-neumann-algebras

Let $(\mathcal{M}, \tau)$ be a tracial von Neumann algebra, that is, $\tau$ is a faithful normal trace on $\mathcal{M}$. Let $S$ be a WOT dense unital $*$-subalgebra of $\mathcal{M}$.

Given another tracial von Neumann algebra $(\mathcal{N}, \nu)$ and an algebraic $*$-homomorphism $\varphi: S \to \mathcal{N}$ that preserves the trace ($\nu \circ \varphi =\tau$), **can we always extend $\varphi$ to a a trace preserving $*$-homomrphism from $\mathcal{M}$ to $\mathcal{N}$?**

This situation has arised many times when dealing with separable von Neumann algebras, where $\varphi$ is defined on some countable dense subalgebra, and one would like to extend to all of $\mathcal{M}$ (for example, when $\mathcal{M} = L(\Gamma)$ for some countable group $\Gamma$, and $S$ is the algebra generated by the canonical unitaries $\{u_\gamma \vert \gamma \in \Gamma\}$). Yet for some reason, in the literature I encountered, this is often ignored or considered as trivial.

My approach for explaining this was using the 2-norms induced by the traces $\Vert x \Vert_{2,\tau} = \tau (x^*x), \; \Vert \cdot \Vert_{2, \nu}$, which turn out to be complete on the unit balls of $\mathcal{M, N}$, and capture the WOT density of $S$. However, I hit a severe roadblock since I do not assume $\varphi$ respects the operator norm in any way, and I do not see how in general trace preservation should say something about this.

Any reference or help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't require $\nu$ to be faithful, then answer is no. For instance take $M=L^\infty[0,1]$, with $\tau$ integration against Lebesgue measure. Take $N=L^\infty[0,1]\oplus L^\infty[1,2]$, with $\nu$ given by $\nu(f\oplus g)=\tau(f)$. Let $S$ be the polynomials, and $\varphi(p)=p\oplus p$. Then $\nu\circ\varphi=\tau$, but $\varphi$ is not contractive, so it cannot extend to a $*$-homomorphism of C$^*$-algebras.

If we require that $\nu$ is faithful and that $\varphi$ has dense image, then it can be extended. To see this, consider $M$ and $N$ represented in GNS for $\tau$ and $\nu$ respectively. Let $\Omega_\tau, \Omega_\nu$ denote the corresponding cyclic vectors, then:
\begin{align}
\frac{\|\varphi(x)\varphi(z)\Omega_\nu\|^2}{\|\varphi(z)\Omega_\nu\|^2}
&=\frac{\langle \varphi(xz)\Omega_\nu,\varphi(xz)\Omega_\nu\rangle}{\langle \varphi(z^*z)\Omega_\nu,\Omega_\nu\rangle}\\[0.3cm]
&=\frac{\nu(\varphi(z^*x^*xz)}{\nu(\varphi(z^*z))}=\frac{\tau(z^*x^*xz)}{\tau(z^*z)}\\[0.3cm]
&=\frac{\|xz\Omega_\tau\|^2}{\|z\Omega_\tau\|^2}.
\end{align}
Taking the supremum all nonzero $z$, we get
$$
\|\varphi(x)\|=\|x\|.
$$
Note that $\varphi(z)=0$ implies $\tau(z^*z)=\nu(\varphi(z^*z))=0$, and $z=0$, so $\varphi$ is faithful.

Comment: Thanks a ton! I have two questions: Firstly, is it necessary to require dense image? To me it seems like you can always replace $(\mathcal{N}, \nu)$ with the WOT or norm closure of $\varphi(S)$ and equip it with the induced trace, though I maybe missing something. Secondly, is this found somewhere in the literature, Diximier/Takesaki perhaps? Or did you come up with a solution? Thanks again

Comment: Yeah, I think you are right about the dense image. I don't recall seeing this in books, but not saying it isn't. The idea of using the polynomials I don't know where I learnt it from, but they are the canonical example of a "bad" $*$-algebra because of the lack of inverses and the possibility of norming it in many ways. The GNS idea seemed natural when trying to express the norm using the states.

Comment: Super, thanks foe the great answer!

Answer (score 1):

Another way to see this is to use that $\phi$ preserves not only the $2$-norm, but all $p$-norms $\lVert x\rVert_p=\tau(\lvert x\rvert^p)^{1/p}$ with $p=2k$, $k\in \mathbb N$ (to ensure that $\lvert x\rvert^p$ is in $S$). Then one can use $\lVert x\rVert=\lim_{k\to\infty}\lVert x\rVert_{2k}$ to get
$$
\lVert \phi(x)\rVert=\lim_{k\to\infty}\nu((\phi(x)^\ast \phi(x))^k)^{\frac 1 {2k}}=\lim_{k\to\infty}\nu(\phi((x^\ast x)^k))^{\frac 1{2k}}=\lim_{k\to\infty}\tau((x^\ast x)^k)^{\frac 1{2k}}=\lVert x\rVert.
$$

Comment: Cool! Is it hard to prove the non-commutative analog of convergence of $p$-norms? If so, do you have a reference?

Comment: @pitariver It's not hard. First you can restrict to positive elements, because the $p$-norm  of an element and its absolute value coincide. For positive (or more generally self-adjoint) elements you can reduce this problem to the commutative case using the spectral theorem.

Comment: Great explanation! Thanks.